# Robot Framework's SeleniumLibrary throws an error "chromedriver.exe is not a supported browser"

Tags: python, selenium, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework

I am doing some automation test script for login scenario using Robot framework with Python. But when we run the first test case in the suite, it displays error and all test cases fail because chrome/gecko driver is not being supported.

We have done all installattion and webdriver path setting (geckodriver and chromedriver)C:\python\scripts\chromedirver.exe

Test Script:

```
*** Settings ***
Library           Selenium2Library

*** Variables ***
${LoginUserType}    Type=email    # Login user email field.
${ClickNextButtonXpath}    xpath=//span[contains(text(),'Next')]    # Click on next button.
${UserPasswordName}    name=password    #Login user password field.
${NextButtonXpath}    xpath=//span[contains(text(),'Next')]    # User click on next button.
${UserProfileIcon}    //a[@class='gb_x gb_Da gb_f']    # Vefify that icon user profile.
${Geckodriver}    C:\\Users\\mahendra\\Downloads\\geckodriver-v0.24.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe
${chromedriver}    C:\\Users\\mahendra\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe

*** Test Cases ***
Valid user login
    [Documentation]    Login Test Cases 
    ... Step 1. Open browser. 
    ... Step 2. Enter user email 'mahendra.seervi@connexistech.com' in user email field. 
    ... Step 3. Click on next button. 
    ... Step 4. Enter user password 'mahendra2020kag' in user password field. 
    ... Step 5. Click on next button. Step 6. Verify that 'logout' link should display.

    Open Browser    https://www.gmail.com    ${chromedriver}
    Maximize Browser Window
    Wait Until Element Is Visible    \    30
    Input Text    ${LoginUserType}    mahendra.seervi@connexistech.com
    Click Element    ${ClickNextButtonXpath}
    Input Text    ${UserPasswordName}    2586355
    Click Element    ${NextButtonXpath}
    Page Should Contain Element    ${UserProfileIcon}

*** Keywords ***
Set Environment Variable
    Set Environment Variable    webdriver.geckodriver.driver    ${Geckodriver}
    Set Environment Variable    webdriver.chromedriver.driver    ${chromedriver}
```

Error:

```
Starting test: Demo1.Login.Login Suite.Valid user login
20190411 11:03:45.982 :  INFO : Opening browser 
'C:\Users\mahendra\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe' to base url 'https://www.gmail.com'.
20190411 11:03:45.982 :  INFO : Cannot capture screenshot because no browser is open.
20190411 11:03:46.060 :  FAIL : ValueError: c:\users\mahendra\downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe is not a supported browser.
Ending test:   Demo1.Login.Login Suite.Valid user login
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error comes from how you call `Open Browser` - you are passing to it the location to the driver exe, but it expects something different - a string with the browser name. E.g. this:

```
Open Browser    https://www.gmail.com    ${chromedriver}
```

must actually be like this:

```
Open Browser    https://www.gmail.com    Chrome
```

If you want to have a custom location for the webdriver (chromedriver in your case), custom as not in the user's path, you have 2 options - add it there on the runtime:

```
Append To Environment Variable      PATH    C:\\Users\\mahendra\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\
```

*(that keyword is in the `OperatingSystem` library)*

, or use the `Create Webdriver` keyword for instantiating a driver:

```
Create Webdriver     Chrome     executable_path=${chromedriver}
```